# Letting add class name in GWT CellList parent row element

Tags: gwt

CellList from GWT have 4 class names: keyboardSelectedItem, SelectedItem, EventItem and OddItem.

I just need to add another one.

I was thinking in overriding:

```
@Override
      protected void renderRowValues(SafeHtmlBuilder sb, List<T> values, int start,
          SelectionModel<? super T> selectionModel) { ... }
```

And adding another custom class just like :

```
classesBuilder.append(anotherClass);
```

Is this the best approach? another idea?